# Multiple tables entry by a single action

Tags: php, sql, database

I made a form for pharma products where you can select the manufacturer and write the name of the product. Lets say if a user did mistake then we shout the user to correct your input please. For this purpose we are doing validation on front end and back-end but that entry goes in to the database,
eg: When user choose the username if its already exists then the message appers this user already exist please change the username but the entry goes to the database.

Now for Second phase SELECT the Data from 1 table do some validation and save it into another table. What i want is how to do that ? I mean i did tried this code no error but the data not save into the 2nd table.

php:

```
   //Select Everything from database
$perm = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result34 = mysqli_query($dbc, $perm);

if ($perm) {
  //How many rows
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result34);

  //Retrieve data

  if($count==1) {

    $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result34);
    $namex= $rows['name'];
    $categoryx = $rows['category'];

    //takeout the spaces and strip tags

    $namey = strip_tags($namex);
    $category = str_replace(' ', '', $category);


    //INSERT INTO TABLES

    $sql34 = "INSERT INTO final1 (Name, Category) VALUES ($namey, $category);";
    $result55 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql34);
      }
    }
```

EDIT: prepared statement

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO final1 (Name, Category) VALUES (?, ?);";
    $stmt1 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbc);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt1, $sql2)) {
      echo "SQL error";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "ss", $namey, $category);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
    }
```

Comment: if you are inserting strings the values should be quoted

Comment: You mean like this ?
$sql34 = "INSERT INTO final1 ('Name', 'Category') VALUES ($namey, $category);";

Comment: just tried this 
 $sql34 = "INSERT INTO final1 ('Name', 'Category') VALUES ('$namey', '$category');"; still not working

Comment: Values !== column names

Comment: Although prpepared statements with bind variables is a much better approach

Comment: @MARK i tried this $sql34 = "INSERT INTO final1 (Name, Category) VALUES ('$namey', '$category');"; still not getting data to second table.

Comment: also tried with prepared statement..
just edit the question  ..

Comment: use `mysqli_query` instead of `mysqli_stmt_execute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay Thanks all of you guys..

just change

`$count >=1` now problem solved !! 
Thanks